# iOS simulator Landscape Portrait

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation, landscape-portrait

I have a iOS application which has been build on XCode earlier iOS 5 and supports the `Landscape left ,  Landscape right and portrait (bottom home )` and from the `info.plist` --> `support interface orientation` --> `1 landscape(right home button) 2 landscape(left home button) 3 portrait (bottom home )` to flow of the opening app

Means simulator will open `landscape(right home button)` by default..

but problem is when I run app in simulator `iOS 5.0` --> `landscape(right home button)`  opens by default .

but when i run app in simulator `iOS 6.1` --> `Portrait mode opens by default.`

why iOS 6.1 simulator is opening the Portrait mode when I have set `landscape(right home button)` to open by default.

is there any issue with the base SDK or anything..as I was building on the earlier versions of the iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The way interface orientations are handled changed in iOS 6. The two main methods to look into are as below :

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

and

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
```

both declared in `UIViewController`.

I'd recommend to read [View Controller Programming Guide - Supporting Multiple Interface Orientations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html)

Comment: ya done the same ... in `supportedInterfaceOrientations --> ?UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait `  and in `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight }`  but still ios 6.1 simulator opening portrait view by default